# Calling a view inside a view

Tags: view, laravel

Is it possible to call a view inside a view in Laravel?

```
<div id="main_content">
    <?php View::make('content_view'); ?>
</div>
```

like it nicely worked in Codeigniter

```
<div id="main_content">
    <?php $this->load->view('content_view'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont 'call' a view, you ['include' the view - see template docs for more examples at Laravel.com](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating)

```
<div id="main_content">
    @include('content_view')
</div>
```